# Install QGIS Server with Apache

Tags: qgis, apache

I'm installing QGIS Server with Apache.
I manage to install but I notice that I get a 302 code. attraverso questo comando:

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi
```

I created the file as the guide says
qgis.demo.conf

It's not clear to me if I need to replace the IP address.
"In the following, please replace qgis.demo with the name or IP address of your server."

so I should call the ip_address.conf file and change the contents of serverName ip_address

Being local on a VM I had tried calling the localhost.conf file and inserting localhost into ServiceName

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName qgis-server

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  # Apache logs (different than QGIS Server log)
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/qgis-server-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/qgis-server-access.log combined

  # Longer timeout for WPS... default = 40
  FcgidIOTimeout 120

  FcgidInitialEnv LC_ALL "en_US.UTF-8"
  FcgidInitialEnv PYTHONIOENCODING UTF-8
  FcgidInitialEnv LANG "en_US.UTF-8"

  # QGIS log
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_STDERR 1
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL 0

  # default QGIS project
  SetEnv QGIS_PROJECT_FILE /home/qgis/projects/world.qgs

  # QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH must lead to a directory writeable by the Server's FCGI process user
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH "/home/qgis/qgisserverdb/"
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_AUTH_PASSWORD_FILE "/home/qgis/qgisserverdb/qgis-auth.db"

  # Set pg access via pg_service file
  SetEnv PGSERVICEFILE /home/qgis/.pg_service.conf
  FcgidInitialEnv PGPASSFILE "/home/qgis/.pgpass"

  # if qgis-server is installed from packages in debian based distros this is usually /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  # run "locate qgis_mapserv.fcgi" if you don't know where qgis_mapserv.fcgi is
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

 <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
 FcgidMaxRequestLen 26214400
 FcgidConnectTimeout 60
 </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```